# How can I take the entire content located inside the body element and move it inside a div?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to take all the content in a body element, and place it inside a div?

Below is an example, although I do not want to simply add the content of the body, I want to add it inside a div. I am relatively new, so I apologize if my question is unclear and my limited knowledge on what methods to use.

```
let innards = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML += innards;
```

I attempted to add the innerHTML to a div, but it does not seem to work in the same manner. Is there a way to extract the innerHTML?

Comment: You are extracting it already, but you haven't gotten the div to put the content into.

Comment: @caTS sorry, I only added a small snippet. The div is created. I actually found the solution.

It is:

div.innerHTML = innards.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```js
var parent = document.body.parentNode;
var div = document.createElement('div');
var content = document.body
parent.replaceChild(div, content);
div.appendChild(content);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Main Content starts here</p>
<!-- Rest of the html -->
</body>
</html>
```

This will wrap the `<body>` element with a newly created `div` element. This is generic code. You can apply this for any element.